# REST API SkypeBot suggested actions

Tags: php, botframework, skype, skype-bots

Trying to make REST API skype bot but have a problem with a suggested actions message.
I prepare JSON with code like this:

```
$message = [
        "type" => "message",
        "from" => [
            "id" => $clientid,
        ],
        "conversation" => [
            "id" => $chatid,
        ],
        "recipient" => [
          "id" => $chatid,
        ],
        "text" => "Color",
        "inputHint" => "expectingInput",
        "suggestedActions" => [
            "to" => [ $reptoid ],
            "actions" => [
                [
                    "type" => "imBack",
                    "title" => "Blue",
                    "value" => "Blue"
                ],
                [
                    "type" => "imBack",
                    "title" => "Green",
                    "value" => "Green"
                ],
            ],
        ],
        "replyToId" => $replyid
    ];
```

And after I send - I get in skype only text, wihout any buttons.
What I'm doing wring?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [Channel Inspector](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/channel-inspector/channels/Skype?f=SuggestedActions&e=example1), it seems that `Suggested Actions` in Skype are only available in the context of Cards.

[image]